# Why did the Omega trick William Cage to the Bavarian Alps dam?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

In "Edge of Tomorrow", Cage and Rita make a plan to get out of the beach, and head to a location (a dam) in the Bavarian Alps that Cage had seen in his visions in order to wipe out the Omega.

But, as it turns out:

> It was a trap; the Omega knew Cage and Rita were coming after it. So it planted a false vision to send them to the Alps, so it could rid Cage of his connection to the Omega.

So two questions:

1. We know that the Verdun victory was planned by the Omega to make the humans believe they could win and throw more resources into the war, as per the dialogue. But what did the Omega intend to do with Cage?
2. Why trick Cage into coming all the way to an isolated location in the Bavarian Alps to make him lose his power? Why not find some other location (example, the barn)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The movie does not actually have a canon answer to either question, however, we can make some reasonable guesses as to possible answers.

As to what the Omega intended to do with Cage - that's the trickier question. It may have just been a simple ruse to cause the humans to waste resources going after a false target. It might have intended to capture him, perhaps study him to learn more about humanity and how they are able to form a connection to the Omega in the first place.

The question of location is easier. When attempting to trick the enemy, the trick must be *credible*. Mountain locations are generally much easier to defend from attack. An isolated location would be well hidden from casual discovery. The facility in question has a suitable space for holding and hiding the Omega. Anyone given this location would not be inclined to question the authenticity of the intelligence.

Answer (score 15):

I got the impression it was so that the Alpha that William killed could 'steal the magic back'.

Note how the Alpha and Beta that trapped William separated him from his weapons and gave him a wound that *bled heavily*.  Then they effectively stood back, waiting for him to bleed out.<sup>1</sup>  Whatever it was that allowed William to reset the day was supposedly in his blood.

Realizing their strategy, William acts as if he's going to escape through a small space.  The Alpha comes crashing after him, destroying walls and water pipes as it goes. When the space becomes flooded, he drowns.

Their trap failed because of his quick thinking as to how to end his own life with no access to weapons.

1. I'm guessing there was a final stage to the Alpha regaining it's reset power (e.g. drinking the blood) that we never got to see due to William's quick thinking.

Comment: It appeared to me as if it was the loss of the blood at the moment of death that causes the loss of power and this was the goal, not the transfer of power. Evidence - a blood transfusion has the same effect.

Comment: @Gusdor  Yes, you might be right.  Either way, it was connected to his blood.

Answer (score 7):

**The Omega lured him to regain the ability to reset.**

Cage had stolen the Omega's ability to reset the day. This is why Cage was continually adapting, but the Mimics were not. The Omega wanted to gain it back, as it had with Rita.

When Cage shows up at the dam, a Mimic cuts him. Cage yells "Finish it", but the Alpha doesn't. When he tries to shoot himself, the Alpha knocks his gun away. Evidently, the Mimics are trying to make him bleed. Rita (and later Cage) lost the power after a blood transfusion. Presumably, bleeding out has the same effect.

The Omega wanted to make Cage bleed out, but it didn't know where Cage was. Rita and Dr. Carter said he saw the visions because the Omega was "searching" for him. They were right, but not in a way that they knew. The Omega was going to "find" whoever had stolen the power because he was the only human that was going to show up at the dam in the Alps.

**The Omega lured him to a remote location because it was believable and effective.**

It had to be believable enough that no one would smell a trap. If that happened, the Omega would have lost its only way to fight back. The Omega placed it fake location in a remote location in the heart of Mimic-controlled territory.

Since it needed Cage to bleed out, it needed a controlled location. He needed to be alone, so no one could interfere. Indeed, the choice of location caused Cage to finally, reluctantly go alone.

Comment: By "*The Omega lured him to regain the ability to reset.*" I believe you meant, at a time there can only be one creature possessing the ability to reset time. So, for some time, William was alone who had this power since Mimics didn't improvise but William and Rita did with the time loops. My question is how Omega regained his original ability of time reset when blood transfusion took place for William?

Comment: @Firelord, the power was inherently connected to the Omega. Humans could -- through some process not understood -- take control of triggering it, but the Omega is still key. The natural state is that the Omega triggers resets and remembers them; the humans are only temporarily interfering with that. So there is only *one creature possessing the ability to trigger the reset and remember it*. Normally, that creature is the Omega.